# I have yii php error trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, yii

I get a php yii error:

> trying to get property of non-object.

What is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public function actiondnyparentchild()
{
    $parentTitleId = $_GET['contentTitleId'];
    $query = 'SELECT contentTitleId, marathiTitle FROM dnycontenttitle WHERE contentTitleId IN
        (SELECT childTitleId FROM dnycontentcategories WHERE parentTitleId='.$parentTitleId.')';
    $resultschild = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
    $mainchild = array();
    foreach($resultschild as $ressubdata)
    {
        $mainchild[] = array(
            "parentId" => $ressubdata->contentTitleId
        );
    } 
    echo "{'contents':".CJSON::encode($mainchild)."} ";  
}
```

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: $mainchild[]=array("parentId" =>$ressubdata->contentTitleId); error show in this line

Comment: Then $ressubdata->contentTitleId can be empty. Just check with property_exists of other php built-in functions

Comment: Yes. $ressubdata->contentTitleId  empty. But  var_dump($ressubdata) show data {
    'contents': [
        {
            "parentId": {
                "contentTitleId": "1122",
                "marathiTitle": "\u092d\u093e\u0930\u0924\u093e\u091a\u093e \u092d\u0942\u0917\u094b\u0932 \u0935\u093f\u092d\u093e\u0917"
            }
        },

Comment: That is a json object, store as string in $ressubdata. Search for how to decode a json string e read it.